# Dont know why I have this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, size

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Input {
    static class General_Inputs{
        static int Num_Of_Ppes;
        static int Num_Of_States;
        static int Num_Of_Analysis_Years;
        static int Number_Decision_Variables;
        static int Num_objectives;
        static int Num_Constraints;
        static int[] Num_Alt_Decision_variable=new int[Number_Decision_Variables];  
    }
public static double[][] Get_Inputs(){
    Scanner State_Vector=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of Decision_Variables");
    General_Inputs.Number_Decision_Variables=State_Vector.nextInt();
    for(int Num=0;Num<General_Inputs.Number_Decision_Variables;Num++){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Alternatives for Decision Variable "+(Num+1));
        General_Inputs.Num_Alt_Decision_variable[Num]=State_Vector.nextInt();
    }
    State_Vector.close();
    return Current_Cond_State_Cof_lngth;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    double[][] input=Input.Get_Inputs();
```

The inputs is like this:
Enter the number of Decision_Variables
3
Enter the number of Alternatives for Decision Variable 1
2
This should go three times but it stop at the first decision variable and give the following error I am not sure where is the problem. I understand that this error means the size of the array "Num_Alt_Decision_variable" is zero but why is this I defined this array above, I really tried to search a lot but couldn't find the reason Any help is highly appreciated thanks in advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Input.Get_Inputs(Input.java:48)
    at Input.main(Input.java:66)
```

Comment: Your method returns `Current_Cond_State_Cof_lngth`. Where does it get that variable? It is not declared inside the method, it is never changed inside of the method which makes no sense at all to me. What purpose is the method if the returned value is never changed or acted on?

Comment: You probably need to use a combination of  `Scanner#nextLine`, `Scanner#hasNextInt` and `Scanner#nextInt` intstead

Comment: the Current_Cond_State_Cof_lngth is another matrix that done inside this method. both the Num_Alt_Decision_variable array I just need to get the user input for it and use it in another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static int Number_Decision_Variables; // this is 0 here
    static int Num_objectives;
    static int Num_Constraints;

    // and it's still 0 here.
    static int[] Num_Alt_Decision_variable=new int[Number_Decision_Variables];
```

Number_Decision_Variables is 0 at the time you declare Num_Alt_Decision_variable. So your array is size 0 which is a non-usable array. I suggest that you initialize it with a non-0 number.

Initialize your array **after** this line:

```
General_Inputs.Number_Decision_Variables=State_Vector.nextInt();
```

After you get a realistic value for the Number_Decision_Variables variable.

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I could solve it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Input {
    static class General_Inputs{
        static int Num_Of_Ppes;
        static int Num_Of_States;
        static int Num_Of_Analysis_Years;
        static int Number_Decision_Variables;
        static int Num_objectives;
        static int Num_Constraints;
        static int[] Num_Alt_Decision_variable;  
    }
public static double[][] Get_Inputs(){
    Scanner State_Vector=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of Decision_Variables");
    General_Inputs.Number_Decision_Variables=State_Vector.nextInt();
General_Inputs.Num_Alt_Decision_variable=new int[General_Inputs.Number_Decision_Variables]
    for(int Num=0;Num<General_Inputs.Number_Decision_Variables;Num++){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Alternatives for Decision Variable "+(Num+1));
        General_Inputs.Num_Alt_Decision_variable[Num]=State_Vector.nextInt();
    }
    State_Vector.close();
    return Current_Cond_State_Cof_lngth;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    double[][] input=Input.Get_Inputs();
```